# DELETE Dependencies REST API DELETE_FAILED

Tags: rest-api, help, bulk-delete

When attempting to use REST API to delete multiple object records like so:

`h t t p s://org.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v42.0/composite/sobjects?ids=0010x000000000,a1r0x000000001,a1m0x000000002,a1w0x000000003,a1r0x000000004,a1w0x000000005,a1m0x000000006&allOrNone=true`

I'm getting errors that look like this:

`"success": false,
    "errors": [
       {
         "statusCode": "DELETE_FAILED",
         "message": "Your attempt to delete Test Loan kvNrH could not be 
                     completed because it is associated with the following
                     opportunity history.: OH-00549884\n",
         "fields": []
       }`

However, the **OH-00549884** that the error is complaining about is also in the list of IDs to delete in the URL.

I found that if I have the allOrNone set to false I can run it twice and everything is deleted (however, not a very elegant solution). So I'm trying to do this all in one go. Has anyone had to overcome this issue, or have an approach for overcoming this?

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to delete records belonging to multiple Sobject types.

The [Salesforce Lightning REST Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_composite_sobjects_collections_delete.htm) to Delete Multiple Records with Fewer Round-Trips explains the following Usage Guidelines

> - The `DeleteResult` objects are returned in the order in which the IDs    of the deleted objects were specified.
> - **You can't delete records for multiple object types in one call when one of those types is related to a feature in the Salesforce 
>     Setup area.**

I suspect that point #2 is what is causing an issue in your case.